# SQL Query With Nearest Date for BackFilling

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have two tables.

```
Comments
  - CommentId
  - Comment
  - CreateDate
  - SomeCompositeKey

Exceptions
  - ExceptionId
  - Color
  - CreateDate
  - SomeCompositeKey
  - ...and so on...
```

My Comments table is getting a new `Color` column added to it with a default value of "White".

I will need to backfill and update the new Color field on the `Comments` table. I need to set the `Comments.Color` column to equal the `Exception.Color` based on the nearest `CreateDate` of the Comment and the matching `Exception` (matched based on the `SomeCompositeKey`).

This is using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: How many different colours are there? if there arent that many you could just use an update with a case statement on the createdate field.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Comments', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #Comments;
    CREATE TABLE #Comments (
        CommentId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        Comment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
        Color VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT('White')
        );

    INSERT #Comments (CommentId, Comment, CreatedDate)
    SELECT 
        t.n,
        'Blah Blah Blah',
        DATEADD(hh, t.n, GETDATE())
    FROM
        dbo.tfn_Tally(1500, 1) t;
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Exceptions', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #Exceptions;
    CREATE TABLE #Exceptions (
        ExceptionId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        Color VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
        );

    INSERT #Exceptions (ExceptionId, Color, CreatedDate)
    SELECT 
        t.n,
        CASE t.n % 9
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Red'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Blue'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Green'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Yellow'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Purple'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Orance'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Gray'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'White'
            WHEN 8 THEN 'Black'
        END,
        DATEADD(hh, t.n * 13, GETDATE())
    FROM
        dbo.tfn_Tally(100, 1) t;

    -- Add a unique nci on the CreatedDate column to improve performance.
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uix_Exceptions_CreatedDate ON #Exceptions 
        (CreatedDate) INCLUDE (Color);
END;

--=========================================================
-- option 1 (faster when there is an index on e.CreatedDate)
UPDATE c SET
    c.Color = ex.Color
FROM
    #Comments c
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    e.Color
                FROM
                    #Exceptions e
                WHERE 
                    c.CreatedDate >= e.CreatedDate
                ORDER BY 
                    e.CreatedDate DESC
                ) ex;

--=========================================================
-- option 2 (faster when there is not index on e.CreatedDate)
WITH 
    cte_ExceptionRange AS (
        SELECT 
            e.Color, 
            BegData = e.CreatedDate,
            EndDate = LEAD(e.CreatedDate, 1, '9999-12-31') OVER (ORDER BY e.CreatedDate)
        FROM
            #Exceptions e
        )
UPDATE c SET
    c.Color = er.Color
FROM
    #Comments c
    JOIN cte_ExceptionRange er
        ON c.CreatedDate >= er.BegData
        AND c.CreatedDate <er.EndDate;
```

HTH, Jason

Answer (score 0):

Check this query , it may helps you to achieve what you need

```
;with data 
as
(
  Select ExceptionId,Color, SomeCompositeKey
  ,row_number() over  (partition by SomeCompositeKey order by CreateDate desc) rowNumber 
  from   Exceptions
)
  update Comments set newColor=d.Color 
  from data d where d.rowNumber=1 
  and Comments.SomeCompositeKey=d.SomeCompositeKey
```